# Overriding providers on a test-by-test basis in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I would like to override a service provider when testing Ngrx Effects on a per-test basis to cover a success and failure response.

What I've tried so far is providing my service in the TestBed as such:

```
describe('Account Effects', () => {

  let actions: ReplaySubject<any>;
  let effects: AccountEffects;
  let store: Store<IAccountsState>;

  const email = 'someone@gmail.com';
  const password = 'abc123!';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        AccountEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
        provideMockStore<IAccountsState>({ initialState }),
        {
          provide: AccountsService,
          useValue: { _signIn: () => of(null) }
        }
      ]
    });

   store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });


  beforeEach(async () => {
    effects = TestBed.get(AccountEffects);
  });
});
```

Then in each test, override the provider:

```
describe('signIn$ success', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.overrideProvider(AccountsService, {
      useValue: {
        _signIn: () => of({ authenticated: true })
      }
    });
  });
    
  it('should dispatch signInSuccess when a successful response is received', () => {
    actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions.next(AccountActions.signIn({ email, password }));
    
    effects.signIn$.subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual(AccountActions.signInSuccess({ email }));
    });
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that in the test, `accountService._signIn` is not a function:

> An error was thrown in afterAll TypeError:
>
> this.accountsService._signIn is not a function

I need to be able to override the value returned in each test case.

I have been following:

https://indepth.dev/testing-and-faking-angular-dependencies/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where does the `effects` variable come from? from what I understand it's probably injecting AccountsService somewhere, but I can't see where it comes from. If you're using the injector from the test bed before you override it to get the effects value, then it won't include the override.

Comment: I've updated the sample code to show where `effects` is defined. I also tried moving the `provide` for the AccountService above the AccountEffects in the providers list, but I got the same error

Comment: but where does the `effects` variable get assigned? You can't mock what's injected into that class if the value is already assigned unless you're using the injector directly in that class, which isn't recommended.

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally left out the beforeEach that assigns the effects from the TestBed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change the mocking of AccountsService .Account serrvice is a class and you are mocking with a function. You should change the spec as below

```
class  AccountsServiceMock {
    _signIn(){
       of(null)
    }
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AccountEffects,
    provideMockActions(() => actions),
    provideMockStore<IAccountsState>({ initialState }),
    {
      provide: AccountsService,
      useClass: AccountsServiceMock 
    }
  ]
});
```

If you want to change the return value of signin in each spec , you can spyOn it and set the return the value.Hopes this will do the job.

Comment: This strategy seems to be working as far as returning a different value for the Observable, but I'm having difficulty testing the `catchError` scenario. I've tried using `.and.throwError('error)` but that isn't causing the `catchError` to be triggered in the Effect. Ideas?

Comment: did you tried  and.returnValue(throwError('error)) ?

Comment: Thats great to hear.

Answer (score -1):

So I can't be totally sure but I would guess you're having trouble because of when you get your effects instance (though I'm not super familiar with Ngrx). Because you're using ioc the effects instance gets created before you assign a value to actions and before you change the definition of `AccountsService` so your test sort of looks like this:

```
it('should dispatch signInSuccess when a successful response is received', () => {
  let accountsService: AccountsService = {
    _signIn: () => of({ authenticated: true })
  };
  let actions;
  let effects = new AccountEffects(actions, accountsService);
  accountsService = {
    _signIn: () => of({ authenticated: true })
  };

  actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
  actions.next(AccountActions.signIn({ email, password }));

  effects.signIn$.subscribe(result => {
    expect(result).toEqual(AccountActions.signInSuccess({ email }));
  });
});
```

Now I'm not totally sure why it's not seeing that first `_signIn` function. I'd try logging the value of `accountsService` to console in your effects class to see what's going on, but either way you're going to run into some issues based on the order in which you're defining your values.

So in order to fix your test I would start by assigning effects inside your test to see if that works. Then you can adjust things as needed to make sure you can override the values when you want.

So something like this:

```
  it('should dispatch signInSuccess when a successful response is received', () => {
    actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions.next(AccountActions.signIn({ email, password }));
    effects = TestBed.get(AccountEffects);

    effects.signIn$.subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual(AccountActions.signInSuccess({ email }));
    });
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to use this strategy as I wasn't able to pass the mock AccountService instance to the Effect class this way. Thank you very much for the help though, I certainly appreciate it.